# How do robots respond to no user-agent in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I'm just curious because I can't seem to find any mention of it anywhere. What is the standard (or at the very least typical) response to robots.txt *without* a user-agent parameter? Does it assume the following rules apply to it just as `User-agent: *` would or does it ignore them completely?

For example, would a robots.txt containing only `Disallow: /` block all/most standard crawlers or would it do nothing at all?

Comment: your question is impossible to answer. They all behave differently. There are rules  (http://www.robotstxt.org/) but no one has to follow them

Answer (score 2):

Bots would simply ignore this.

I'd expect them to look for specific user agents that they need to take note of. So Googlebot for example would look for User-agent: * or User-agent: Googlebot.

So as those two are missing then the'd probably go ahead and crawl the entire site.

We all know that adding user-agents is essential in robots.txt so there's no point trying to second guess them.

Answer (score 1):

A `Disallow` field that does not follow a `User-agent` field (ie. is not part of a group) is invalid. Bots *should* ignore this as being invalid. However, the rules that govern robots.txt are not a strict standard, so as with anything "invalid" in this respect, robot behaviour could be *unpredicatble*.

The [Original robots.txt standard (1994)](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) simply states:

> The record starts with one or more User-agent lines, followed by one or more Disallow lines, as detailed below. **Unrecognised headers are ignored.**

In this respect, a `Disallow` field could be seen as an "unrecognised header". (?)

In the 1997 Internet Draft specification: [A Method for Web Robots Control](http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt) it states, with respect to the User-agent line:

> If no such
>      record exists *[ie. a specific user-agent match]*, it should obey the first record with a User-agent
>      line with a "*" value, if present. If no record satisfied either
>      condition, or no records are present at all, access is unlimited.

The [Google docs (Robots.txt specifications)](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt?hl=en#grouping-of-records) state that a `disallow` field is "only valid as a group-member record" and a `user-agent` field indicates the "start of group". The Google docs also include a more formal definition which indicates that an entry must start with a "startgroupline" (ie. a `user-agent` field).

If you test this in the "robots.txt Tester" in Google Search Console (formerly Google Webmaster Tools) then any `Disallow` field that is not part of a group (ie. does not start with a `User-agent` field) is simply flagged as an error and is ignored.